# Issue with custom Toast with color

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I trying to make a custom toast with the background "Orange color", however, in the attempt I am able to get it but the field also becomes white and the text is not visible, I have attached the image

[image]

You can see that the text is not visible.

here is my code:

```
            String g= "+";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click and hold on '"+g+"' icon", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            View view= toast.getView();
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF791B"));

            View t = toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            t.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            toast.show();
```

I just want the text to be in white.
Is something I am missing in the code, I am not able to get it right.
Also, is there a way to make the "+" sign bold `g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mode some changes here:

```
TextView t = toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            t.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

I have saved it as textView and I was able to get the `setTextColor` method and I was able to change the color

Answer (score 2):

**Just Change this line**

```
  t.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

**To**

```
   t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: it seems like the `.setTextColor` method is not available here

Answer (score 1):

Try this - customttoast.xml is your custom toast xml and custom_toast_layout can be your activity layout xml

```
        //Creating the LayoutInflater instance  
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();  
        //Getting the View object as defined in the customtoast.xml file  
        View layout = li.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));  
  
        //Creating the Toast object  
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());  
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);  
        toast.setView(layout);//setting the view of custom toast layout  
        toast.show();
```

Comment: this one becomes lengthy, with more code. But this way really works, however, having less code is way more efficient for app-based with the server.